# Cauchy Schwarz master class exercise 1.8 c: Integral comparison

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Exercise 1.8 c is as follows: Proof that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\sqrt{n+k}} < \sqrt{\log(2)} \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k^2)} {}{} \tag{1} $$

In the solution manual the author starts from the following inequality:
$$\frac{1}{n+k} < \int_{n+k-1}^{n+k} \frac{dx}{x} \tag{2}$$ 
From this inequality it follows that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} < \int_{n}^{2n} \frac{dx}{x} = \log(2) \tag{3}$$

The rest of the proof is just applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

I can follow this reasoning, however, when seeing the inequality to prove (1), inequality (2) would never cross my mind. Where does this inequality come from? Is it well known? To me, it seems far fetched to go from log(2) to ineq.(2).

Is there anybody who could give me some more background information, or details about the author's reasoning?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality (2) is an example of an integral comparison:

$$
f(n) \leq C\int_{n-1}^n f(x)dx
$$ You might need to choose the constant $C$ to be something other than $1$, but in your case you have a strictly decreasing function, so 
$$
f(n) < \int_{n-1}^n f(x)dx
$$ is always true.  This idea comes from doing Riemann sums using the "right-endpoint-rule" (picture updated, hopefully better):

[image]

This is a common estimation technique.  Once you've seen it a few times, it becomes part of your toolbox - if you need to estimate something like a sum, try to compare it to an integral so that you can use integral calculus to compute something explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I see now: This seems to be a special case of the following inequality: $ m(b-a) \le \int_{a}^b f(x) dx \le M (b-a)$, with m and M such that $m \le f(x) \le M $

Answer (score 0):

By C-S $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\sqrt{n+k}}\right)^2\leq  \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}<\ln2,$$
which you know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, you write I should know that the above sum is smaller than ln 2, but actually it is not so obvious for me. Could you perhaps provide me with a hint for a proof, or a reference?

Comment: @Birgitte Because $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}<\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\int\limits_{n+k-1}^{n+k}\frac{1}{x}dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\ln(n+k)-\ln(n+k-1))=\ln2n-\ln{n}=\ln2$